# Split a dataframe by length of characters

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a table like

```
--------------------|
Val
--------------------|
1, M A ,HELLO,WORLD |
2, M 1A,HELLO WORLD |
---------------------
```

I want to split the above dataframe so it contains the three columns below.

```
----------------------
a | b   | c          |
----------------------
1 | M A | HELLO,WORLD|
1 | M 1A| HELLO WORLD|
----------------------
```

I have used the below code, but it does not work as expected. Is there a way to contain all characters after 5 characters in column *c*, etc. and character 2-5 in column *b*?

```
df = df.withColumn('Splitted', F.split(hadf37dr_df['Val'], ',')).withColumn('a', F.col('Splitted')[0]).withColumn('b', F.col('Splitted')[1]).withColumn('c', F.col('Splitted')[2])
```

Comment: is it pandas or spark question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to this in [PySpark](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/pyspark/index.htm), you need *F.concat_ws* which concatenates elements of a list and return it as string, and you need *F.slice* which slices elements of a list from 'head' with a specified 'length'. Because you need to set the length, you need the size of the array which you can have with *F.size*.

```
(
    df
    .withColumn('Splitted', F.split(df['val'], ','))
    .withColumn('a', F.col('Splitted')[0])
    .withColumn('b', F.col('Splitted')[1])
    .withColumn(
        'c',
        F.concat_ws(
            ',',
            F.slice('Splitted', 3,  F.size('Splitted') - 2)))
).show()
```

Output:

```
+-------------------+--------------------+---+-----+-----------+
|                val|            Splitted|  a|    b|          c|
+-------------------+--------------------+---+-----+-----------+
|1, M A ,HELLO,WORLD|[1,  M A , HELLO,...|  1| M A |HELLO,WORLD|
|2, M 1A,HELLO WORLD|[2,  M 1A, HELLO ...|  2| M 1A|HELLO WORLD|
+-------------------+--------------------+---+-----+-----------+
```

Comment: Why is it F.size -2 can I ask

Comment: slice function is working with parameters of head: start index, and length so the result would be something like list[head : head + length] in python. because you want two first elements in other col so you need to set head to 3 (it start indexing from 1 instead of 0) and because you want all other elements to concat and you need to know size of array to have something like [2:size] and because you skipped 2 first elements so you need size - 2 as length

Answer (score 1):

If splitting the strings from your original table df with column 'Val' is just based on positions (as you write), you can slice them as follows to obtain df1

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['a', 'b', 'c'], 
                   data = [[row[0], row[2:7], row[8:]] for row in df.Val]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `df.Val.str.extract(...)` to split a string column into multiple columns.
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html

If you are having this issue because the file you are reading is actually formatted in fixed-width instead of comma-separated for example you might want to use `read_fwf(...)` from the pandas library to avoid this problem in the first place.
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_fwf.html

Answer (score 0):

Why *split a dataframe by length of characters* to achieve a goal for splitting based on the first occurrence of comma? If so,

```
df = pd.DataFrame([i.split(',', 1) for i in df.Val], columns=['b', 'c'])
```

Gives #

```
   b             c
0  M A   HELLO,WORLD
1  M 1A  HELLO WORLD
```

Comment: Can the same be done in pyspark

Comment: What do you mean by *"Gives #"*?